# What's get_products() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to program for a friend of mine for fun and practice to make myself better in Python 3.6.3, I don't really understand why I got this error.

```
TypeError: get_products() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have done some research, it says I should initialize the object, which I did, but it is still giving me this error. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Or is there any better ways to do it?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep
from gdax.public_client import PublicClient
# import pandas
import requests

class MyGdaxHistoricalData(object):
    """class for fetch candle data for a given currency pair"""

def __init__(self):
    print([productList['id'] for productList in PublicClient.get_products()])
    # self.pair = input("""\nEnter your product name separated by a comma. 
    self.pair = [i for i in input("Enter: ").split(",")]
    self.uri = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/{pair}/candles'.format(pair = self.pair)

@staticmethod
def dataToIso8681(data):
    """convert a data time object to the ISO-8681 format

    Args:
        date(datetime): The date to be converted
    Return:
        string: The ISO-8681 formated date

    """

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
import gdax

MyData = MyGdaxHistoricalData()
# MyData = MyGdaxHistoricalData(input("""\nEnter your product name separated by a comma.

# print(MyData.pair)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you missed to create object of `PublicClient`. Try `PublicClient().get_products()`

**Edited:**

> why I need the object of PublicClient?

Simple thumb rule of OOP's, if you wanna use some property(attribute) or behavior(method) of class, you need a object of that class. Else you need to make it `static`, use `@staticmethod` decorator in python.

Comment: You are right. Could explain why I need the object of PublicClient?